# android.app.ActivityManager.AppTask accessing a Static class' non static method

Tags: java, android, scope, static, non-static

I know this has been asked, but I seem not te be able to solve this.  I am trying to access the Static `AppTask` class non static public void method `finishAndRemoveTask`.  But I received alot of errors with no success at compile time.

```
import static android.app.ActivityManager.AppTask;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ExitMyApp {
    public void exit() {
            AppTask.finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
}
```

If I do this I get the error `non static method cannot be accessed in static way`. It's understandable as `finishAndRemoveTask` is public void and does not exist yet.  So I instance it:

```
finishAndRemoveTask finandremove = new AppTask.finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Now I get an error `cannot find symbol`.  Can someone give me a clue on how to use the `finishAndRemoveTask` method?

Answer (score 0):

finishAndRemoveTask() is not a static method, so you can't invoke it without an instance, and the way you instantiate it is not correct. You need to obtain a reference to AppTask, like this:

```
    ActivityManager manager =
            (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    for (AppTask task : manager.getAppTasks()) {
        //if task is matching your task/activity
         task.finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
```

Comment: I am importing my java file into a python file and running it from there.  I am trying to close a Kivy App that is running.  The purpose is to `Finishes all activities in this task and remove it from the recent tasks list`, therefore closing my App.  Should this be called on each task?

Comment: if that is your purpose, I don't see why you can't, just close all tasks.

Comment: Is it possible to just call the method `finishAndRemoveTask()` without calling it on eack task?  Thereby stopping the App.

Comment: Given the fact that my class is called externally means that your  variable `context` and method `getPackageManager()` has no instance.  Since my compiler is telling me they do not know where they are coming from.  Also the variable `pm` is declared but not used.

Comment: You try to close an app from another app?

Comment: No from within a Kivy App that is running in android.  The App is written in python and I am trying to close it with java code. I can make a call to native java.  But my java file has to declare all imports and variables explicitly.  E.g. `Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();`.  Then only can I use the `context` variable.